Table columns above header in Chrome
I have a html table with a sticky header. I need to fix it because in Chrome the top of column values can be seen above the header:
Top of table header


<div style="max-height: 700px; overflow-y: auto;">
  <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover">
    <caption hidden></caption>
    <thead style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: white; z-index: 100;">
      <tr class="table-header">
        <th style="width: 5%"></th>
        <th style="width: 10%;text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
          STUFF 1
        </th>
        <th style="width: 10%;text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
          STUFF 2
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">text</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



I tried modifying z-index, the height and padding of the header, using grid.

Please read How to Ask and minimal reproducible example, and then edit your question accordingly. As I cannot reproduce your issue.

The issue with the sticky header in Chrome is likely due to improper stacking context or insufficient height. Adjusting the z-index ensures the header stays on top, and adding padding prevents content from overlapping.
I have had the same issue here but got it fixed.
Simply adjust the 'z-index' and add padding to the 'th' elements.

If CSS isn't enough to handle this issue across all browsers, a JavaScript solution might be necessary. You can use a small script to manually control the positioning of the header
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const tableHeader = document.querySelector('thead');
  const tableHeaderOffset = tableHeader.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  if (tableHeaderOffset <= 0) {
    tableHeader.style.position = 'fixed';
    tableHeader.style.top = '0';
    tableHeader.style.zIndex = '100';
  } else {
    tableHeader.style.position = 'sticky';
    tableHeader.style.top = '0';
  }
});


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
